# Question on Java IO Performance tuning

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to optimize a web based application that does a lot of writing to the stream.
The code is something like this ---

```
 StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(1024);
 PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
```

Then this printwriter is used to do a lot of write operations at several places like --

```
 printWriter.write("set interface ethernet0 zone Trust");
```

I want to optimize the several write operations by wrapping the printwriter around a bufferedwriter. So i plan to change line1 and line2 as below.Please let me know if the approach below is correct --

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(1024);
// go for bufferedwriter instead of printwriter.
BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(stringWriter, 8*1024);
```

Also, I think that now I can replace the write method directly as in --

```
printWriter.write("set interface ethernet0 zone Trust");
```

replaced as

```
bufWriter.write("set interface ethernet0 zone Trust");
```

Please let me know if this is correct or do I need to use any of the overloaded methods of BufferedWriter to take full advantage of the BufferedWriter.

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: @user may i know what are you tryin to achieve from the above code, pls let us know what you want to do in buisness sense.

Comment: I suggest you performance profile your application. If it is too slow, this is highly unlikely to be the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the BufferedWriter only adds an additional copy operation for every char written. You should change the initial size of StringWriter instead, a larger initial size means less growing and less copying later.

The StringWriter itself contains a growing Buffer for character data, adding an additional buffer on top of it by using a BufferedWriter will not lead to a speed up. From the given code a larger initial size for the StringWriter object itself could help.

Comment: Hello,  Thanks for your advice. I have actually used a profiler to analyze the application behavior. I have seen that the application spends almost 70% of the time in the area of the code I am trying to change.

Comment: Basically the application is a conversion tool that translates lines in one format to other. For each line in the ipnut a method is called which calls the printwriter.write() method and so the bulk of the time spent by the application is in this method. For these reasons I am trying to optimize this method and see if the write method can be optimized by going for BufferedWriter instead of PrintWriter. Please advise accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

Since `StringWriter` writes into a string buffer (in memory) per definition, wrapping it into a `BufferedWriter` should not have any effect in performance. (Due to the additional level of indirection, it may in fact make your code a bit slower - although this <strike>will</strike> may be <strike>most likely</strike> optimized away by the JIT compiler.)

The latter is useful in file I/O where one big write tends to be much faster than several small ones.

Why do you think you need to tune this piece of code? It may be worth going through the following

#### General guidelines about performance tuning

1. **Don't do it** (are you sure you need it? Most of the time you actually don't).
2. **Don't do it yet** (relevant classic quote: [*"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) by Donald Knuth).
3. Don't optimize code which you *believe* is slow - **measure the performance with a profiler** to find the actual bottlenecks.
4. **Measure again after any change** to verify that you really improved performance noticeably (case in point: it is easy to make "clever" changes which don't make any difference, or even deteriorate performance).

Comment: The cost of writing to a StringWriter is the cost of copying the data. using a BufferedWriter doubles this cost. I don't believe the JIT can optmise this away.

Comment: Agree with every word. I wanted to write something similar and I am glad I did not. Because I cannot say it so fine.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to be using StringWriter? StringWriter is just a proxy for StringBuffer which synchronises on itself with each time append is called.

Have you considered using StringBuilder instead. It isn't synchronised (and therefore not thread safe), but should be faster -- especially if you are doing lots of short writes.

edit: The synchronisation issue is a doubly important as PrintWriter is also synchronised. Everytime you call print/write your code has to acquire and release two locks. I suspect this might be why you code is spending significant amounts of time in the write method.

edit:
If you really must use PrintWriter then the following alternatives could work, on the caveat that the PrintWriter is only accessed by one thread -- otherwise it could cause a deadlock. To make this work well all writes must be performed in the SAME synchronized block, otherwise you will just hit the same problem -- eg entering and exiting lots of synchronized bits of code.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufSize);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

    synchronized (writer) {
        // do writes
    }

    writer.flush(); // very important or you may not see any output in 'out'
    writer.close();

    String output = out.toString();
```

If you don't have to use a PrintWriter then a StringWriter alone should suffice.

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(bufSize);

    synchronized(writer.getBuffer()) {
        // do writes
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    String output = writer.toString();
```

What was meant to be my initial suggestion:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // do APPENDS (instead of writes)

    String output = builder.toString();
```

That you need to call append instead of write is why you would need to refactor your code.

Comment: Hi Dunes, however I cannot pass StringBuilder as an alternative to StringWriter, as the PrintWriter constructor requires an instance of writer as an argument. So how can I optimized the below code. what alternative data structures can i explore --                   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(1024);      PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);             This is followed by multiple write statements like    printWriter.write()

Comment: So will using a BufferedWriter solve the problem in this case? Please advise.

Comment: No. The BufferedWriter will only make things worse (as others have stated, and also explained why).

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that `BufferedWriter` will give any performance improvement here - both it and `StringWriter` write straight to memory. If anything it will slow things (fractionally) down by adding a layer of indirection. Of course if you find differently please correct me. What makes you think this is a bottleneck?